# How to reuse the code of the containing app for action extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-app-extension

I want to reuse the code of the containing app for action extension with objective c. In the documentation it is written that you cant launch the main/containing app. So how to implement the partial functionality of the app in action extension with reusing the code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file that contains the desired functionality to the extension target. You can change this in a few ways. You can manually add that file to the `Compiled Sources` section for the target under `Build Phases`. Or you can select the file and inspect its `Target Membership` in the `File Inspector` pane on the right hand side.

Comment: Can it be done like creating a framework as in today extension?

Comment: It can, but that is more complicated